# The 5 amp fuse on my AC/Heater control board blows when I put the setting to heat

Tags: heating

The 5 amp fuse on my control board blows as soon as you ask for heat.  With a good fuse in the AC work fine and you can switch the fan from Auto to Fan on with no problem.

As soon as you request heat the fuse blows and when I try to run the fan to on nothing happens.

I read on-line to jump the W and R on the control board and see if the fuse would blow or if the heater would kick on so I did that.  The exhaust motor kicked on then the gas ignited and after a few minutes so did the fan and I had heat.

I assumed it was the low voltage wiring from the wall t-stat to the control board so I got new wire and ran up to the attic.  I even installed a new t-stat.  Exact same problem.  AC works fine but as soon a I switch to heat the fuse blows.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What make and model is your furnace?  Also, do you have any other accessories that run on 24VAC?

Comment: Its a 4 ton Goodman not sure of the make and model.  No other accessories.

Comment: I am having this problem. There are some threads that say the Honeywell B is not the same as blue/common.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed, this page here had some useful leads, mentioned the transformer being bad as a possible cause. That makes sense since the voltage to the board could jump up to line voltage possibly https://www.thecomfortdoctors.com/blog/furnace-blowing-fuse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the furnace control board again jumper the red to the white.  Everything OK?  Now, on the new stat wire, disconnect the Stat completely.  Now at the stat location twist together the red and the white. Does the fuse now hold.  The furnace should start.  If this is the case, you are doing something wrong when you are connecting the stat. Happy hunting and Good Luck.

Comment: Paul,  I did what you suggested (jump the wires inside the house at the t-stat) and the furnace kicked off just like it is supposed to.

Comment: The thing is when I put the stat back on the wall it snaps into place with contact pins touching the set screws so there is nothing I can do wrong there.  I put the stat back on and turned on the AC and the fan all good.  Turned on the heat and it blew the fuse again.  I checked the voltage at the wall while the heater was running and I was getting a little over 27 volts AC but I think that should be fine.  I guess I have two defective honeywell T-stats?!!?!?  Any ideas?

Comment: Well it is possible.  However I am a bit skeptical.  Those things are typically reliable.  Try another one.  If you get the same results, you better look a little closer at your work.

Answer (score 2):

Your thermostat wires or something in the heating circuit are going to ground. Since it works fine when you jump it at the furnace the problem is in the thermostat wire. Since the cooling works fine the problem is in the heating wire (usually W or white). Do you have a C or common wire? If you do it may be touching the common wire. It could also be grounding on the furnace cabinet sometimes it is inside the cable but usually the problem is somewhere you can see. Follow the wire from the W terminal all the way back to the thermostat. You will most likely find the insulation frayed and touching something that goes to ground.

Comment: I replaced the wire from the T-stat in the house to control board on the air handler in the attic so I know it is good.  I even exchanged the t-stat for another new one.  Same problem.  I will check for a grounded wire in inside the unit in the attic.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: I ended up replacing the thermostat with a more expensive unit and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have been dealing with the issue of blowing the 3 amp fuse in my central heater.
I replaced the thermostat over summer and have only been using the A/C until recently. The weather has cooled and I wanted to use the heater, but the fuse blew. I started trying to figure out what was wrong and went through 5 fuses. I figured the only that had changed was the thermostat, so I went back to Lowe's and swapped it out for a new one, thinking I got a dud.
I bought a new pack of fuses and installed the new thermostat. Same thing.
I was down to my last fuse and decided to read the manual. One line stuck out: "If you do not have a heat pump, do not install the blue wire."
I pulled the blue wire, held my breath, and turned on the heater. Viola! No blown fuse!
I guess the blue wire introduces my electricity into the system and blows the fuse.
I hope this helps someone who is in a similar situation!
It all boils down to one thing: Do not wait until you have tried everything else before you RTFM (Read the 'frigging' manual)!

Comment: What make and model of thermostat did you install?!

Comment: It would be handy if you put in an obvious TL;DR: section - I thought you were asking a new question...

Answer (score 0):

For non-heat pump applications, do not connect the black wire to the thermostat. The thermostat shorts the black and red wire terminals together when heat is called for which will blow the fuse every time. The thermostat does not require a ground wire to operate, in a simple furnace system only the red (24vac) and white (heat call) wires are needed.

Comment: Thermostat wire color coding isn't *nearly* as universal as you think, *especially* for heat pumps